# Simple flash application builder?

Tags: flash, programming-languages, wysiwyg

Are there any relatively simple programs for building flash applications.  I want to add a basic card game to my site, that can keep track of the user's score.  The site right now is built in just html, though I will be changing it over to php shortly to implement a log in system.  I'd really like to avoid having to learn actionscript on top of it, there has to be some sort of.. basic wysiwyg type flash builder out there?

Comment: Loosely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this one: [Sprout Builder](http://sproutinc.com/solution/sprout-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder 4.5 is nice. You have your Editor and a Design Mode where you can see how it will look like.

But you would have to learn Actionsscript in Order to get your Card Game working.